# Tryin to display an MDDropDownMenu when click to icon exist in MDToolbar

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I have a problem on my code, i'm trying to use a MDToolBar that contains in icon , i want to when click to this icon it show a MDDropDownMenu, when i click it it give me this error 
`'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_window'` if someone know how to solve it !! any suggestions !! the problem exist exactly in the functions in MyApp Class
`this is main.py`

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivymd.color_definitions import colors
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

Window.size = (360, 600)
class Scanner(Screen):   
    pass
class Connecter(Screen):
    pass    
class Search(Screen):
    pass
class Inscrire(Screen):
    pass        
class Apropos(Screen):
    def back_to_scanner(self):
        self.manager.current = 'scanner'
    pass
class Setting(Screen):
    pass
class MyApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    dropdown = ObjectProperty()
    def on_start(self):
        # Create the dropdown menu
        self.dropdown = MDDropdownMenu(width_mult=2)

        # Add items to the menu
        for i in range(6):
            self.dropdown.items.append(
                {"viewclass": "MDMenuItem",
                 "text": "Option " + str(i),
                 "callback": self.option_callback}
            )

    def option_callback(self, text_of_the_option):
        print(text_of_the_option)

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "DeepPurple"
        return Builder.load_file("main.kv")

MyApp().run()
```

and this is main.kv

```
#:include kv/inscrire.kv
#:include kv/connecter.kv

<MDMenuItem>:
    on_release: app.change_variable(self.text)
NavigationLayout:
    id: nav_layout

    # ScreenManager:


    ScreenManager:
        id: screen_manager    
        Connecter:
            id: connecter
            name: "connecter"

        Inscrire:
            id: inscrire
            name: "inscrire"   
        Screen:
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'

        Scanner:
            id: scanner
            name: "scanner" 

            MDToolbar:
                title: "Scanner"
                elevation: 10
                left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state()]]
                right_action_items: [['magnify', lambda x: scanner.go_to_search()],['dots- vertical',lambda x: app.dropdown.open(x)]]
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'top': 1}
```

Comment: I think you need to add `caller=` to your `self.dropdown = MDDropdownMenu(width_mult=2)` call. Not sure what should be passed with that (can't find any documentation), but it must be a `Widget`.

Comment: @JohnAnderson I did  caller = self.dropdown = MDDropdownMenu(width_mult=2) but not workin ; the same error !

Comment: No, you need to do something like `self.dropdown = MDDropdownMenu(caller=something,width_mult=2)`, where `something` is some `Widget` instance.

Comment: which widget ? that contains the MDToolbar ? can you specify because i'm new on kivymd @JohnAnderson

Comment: Don't know. I can't find any documentation on that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. What i did is, i used simple alternative method to overcome this.
Instead of using "right_action_items", you can add "MDIconButton" to the "MDToolbar".

Here is an example of modifying the kivyMD documentation example:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu

KV = '''
MDScreen:
    MDToolbar:
        title: 'Toolbar'
        pos_hint: {'top': 1}
        MDIconButton:
            id: button
            halign: 'center'
            icon: "dots-vertical"
            pos_hint: {'top': root.y+0.9, 'x': 1}
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
            on_release: app.menu.open()
    
'''


class Test(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.screen = Builder.load_string(KV)
        menu_items = [
            {
                "text": f"Item {i}",
                "viewclass": "OneLineListItem",
                "on_release": lambda x=f"Item {i}": self.menu_callback(),
            } for i in range(5)
        ]
        self.menu = MDDropdownMenu(
            caller=self.screen.ids.button,
            items=menu_items,
            width_mult=4,
        )

    def menu_callback(self, text_item):
        print(text_item)

    def build(self):
        return self.screen


Test().run()
```

I used "pos_hint" to take the icon into the middle of toolbar and changed the color to be white. This works perfectly fine same as the "right_action_items".